# Logical doubt in php as a beginner

Tags: php

A web page(page -1) contains the user inforrmation (like name department and other personal details)

Wep page (page -2) contains three select box(Location,department name and domain name and a view button)(all from database)---resutlt set is obtained

Now in page -1 for a user i have to create a hyperlink to page 2

If ther is a user name john with the department info as  Enggineering then in the department link of the first page should lead to the second page with the direct result set(meaning the user cant select anything in second page in any of the select box)

I am a beginner.How will i do this in PHP..Please help

Comment: This question is really ambiguous. Do you mean you want to have a search page with select boxes and a result site that displays matching info?

Comment: Wait? What's the question already ?

Comment: Code is too huge.let me be clear.There is a page which ask the user to select various option like department,start date,end date (select box).When the user click on the view button(by default it displays all user inforrmation and therir correspornding departments.

Comment: Now i wanted to create a hyperlink which links to that page,so that the result set displays on that of the corresponding user.

Answer (score 1):

Hello as you are at beginning level first of all collect information by reading either by book or online then  only you can easily handle all these problem.

best of luck and google your problem

Answer (score 0):

Using get: have the link like

> page2.php?location=selectedlocation&dept=seldept&domain=seldomain.

Check for matches in the select box during loading.

> if(parseddatalocationfromdb==$_GET['selectedlocation'])
>   { echo'
>
> > 1.. so on';}else { echo 'select without disabled';}

The above code will disable the select boxes, now you can check in the code and right a query to show matching results.